# Python to C++ Communication via SendMessage

Tags: c++, python, ctypes, sendmessage, wm-copydata

I'm using Python2.7 and Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 Professional.

I'm trying to use SendMessage to send a copydatastruct object to a MFC C++ program. The C++ program receives the message fine, however, I cannot figure out the correct data type for the dwData attribute.

The dwData attribute is being checked against variables declared in the C++ code:

```
#define RUN_ASYNC 0x8001
#define RUN_SYNC 0x8002
...
#define RUN_MCS 0x8012
...
```

The OnCopyData function in the C++ code has a basic switch statement:

```
...
switch(pCopyDataStruct->dwData)
{
    case RUN_ASYNC:
        {
            // DO STUFF
        }
        break;
    case RUN_SYNC:
        {
            // DO STUFF
        }
        break;
    ...
    case RUN_MCS:
        {
            // DO STUFF
        }
        break;
    ...
    default:
        TRACE(_T("OnCopyData unknown function"))
        break;
}
```

Since I'm not sending it properly, it never hits the proper case and ends up using the default.

I'm setting up the copydatastruct in my python script as:

```
class COPYDATASTRUCT(Structure):
_fields_ = [("dwData", c_ulong),
            ("cbData", c_uint),
            ("lpData", c_void_p)]
```

and declaring the variables as:

```
RUN_ASYNC = 8001
RUN_SYNC = 8002
...
RUN_MCS = 8012
...
```

This sends the correct four digit number to the C++ program, but it's not being recognized properly for the switch case.

When I declared the variables in the python script as:

```
RUN_ASYNC = 0x8001
RUN_SYNC = 0x8002
...
RUN_MCS = 0x8012
...
```

The C++ program receives a number like 32786 that, of course, doesn't work with the switch statement.

How do I need to declare the variables that I'm going to be sending to the C++ program in the dwData attribute to get them to work with the C++ code. I have a feeling that I'm being really stupid, and missing something relatively simple.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FWIW: 32786 is 0x8012.    is that one of the values in the "..." section of your code?

Comment: Have you tried it with 0x8001 and 0x8002? 32786 is 0x8012 (not sure where the extra bits came from, though).

Comment: Yes, 0x8012 is one of the other options. Sorry about missing that. None of the options work with the switch statement.

Comment: But that's the thing. 32786 is 0x8012 which is RUN_MCS and does work with the switch statement.

Comment: Well, I can honestly say I'm really confused, because it's working now. Only adjustment I made was to switch the numbers back to hex in the python code. Thank you for the help, I'll show myself over to the "Why is it working now?" corner.

Comment: It must have been the do_remove_gremlins() call.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking :)

Comment: Not an issue here, but `dwData` is [a `ULONG_PTR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649010) nowadays. I'd use `c_size_t` or `wintypes.WPARAM`.